# host_vars not working in ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to use `host_vars` in my ansible file to install a package on remote host, i am trying to pull a variable by the name  `package` from `host_vars` dir in which a  file `ansi2` reside  which is the hostname of remote machine,, the name of my main yaml file is `service.yml` and reside in `/etc/ansible` ....

```
---
 - hosts: all
   become: yes
   ignore_errors: yes
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:

   - name: install vim
     yum: name={{ package }} state=present
```

Dir Structure:

```
[root@ansi1 ansible]# pwd
/etc/ansible
[root@ansi1 ansible]#
[root@ansi1 ansible]# ls -l ansi2/host_vars/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19 Jun 13 08:15 ansi2
[root@ansi1 ansible]#


[root@ansi1 ansible]# cat ansi2/host_vars/ansi2
---
package: "vim"
```

Error:

```
TASK [install vim] *************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/service.yml:7
fatal: [ansi2.example.com]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'package' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/service.yml': line 7, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n   tasks:\n   - name: install vim\n     ^ here\n"
}
...ignoring
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your output, inventory hostname is `ansi2.example.com`.
You should change file name `ansi2` to match your inventory hostname.